# Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:c227dc88-59c6-4602-bfd7-f87c994ea995

Tags: sql-server, jsp

I've looked in the internet for the error

> Login failed for user 'sa'

And followed the solutions but I still get it.

Here is my code:

```
package model.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConnectionDB {
    Connection conn;
    String user="sa";
    String pass="12345678";

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;instance=KID\\SQL;databaseName=QLDTTN";
    public Connection getConnectMySQL(){
        //nạp driver
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Không thể nạp driver");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //tạo chuỗi kết nối conn
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Sai tham số kết nối");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConnectionDB c = new ConnectionDB();
            System.out.println(c.getConnectMySQL());
        }
}
```

and this is the error detail:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:c227dc88-59c6-4602-bfd7-f87c994ea995
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at model.dao.ConnectionDB.getConnectMySQL(ConnectionDB.java:24)
    at model.dao.ConnectionDB.main(ConnectionDB.java:36)

null
```

I'm pretty new in JSP and SQL server (I use SQl server 2012).
Thanks a lot